# Android - Gridview with different column number at a certain row

Tags: android, gridview

I was wondering if is it possible to have a GridView with, like, 2 rows with 2 columns and then the other ones 4 columns.
Does anyone knows that?

Comment: Maybe this http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/quiltview-library/ or this http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/pinterest-like-adapterview/ will fit your needs. Plain GridView does not support such functionality, other way is to make custom cell views that will divide equally one cell into two smaller

Answer (score 0):

GridView doesn't support spanning, but GridLayout does. Make a 4-colums GridLayout and set the `android:layout_columnSpan="2"` attribute to the first two views.

Comment: The problem is that i need to load from an online service lots of data and put them in list if the device is a phone, but for tablets i needed a grid visualization. GridLayout, to my knowledge, doesen't support scrolling natively and I need to set a fixed number of rows and columns.